# UML activity diagram - how to set ending nodes for sub activities?

Tags: uml

in an activity dgm .. if an activity involves two sub activities..

```
should i make separate ending nodes for sub activities? 
Should I make one ending node for main activity only ?
```

This is what i wants to say

[image: activity dgm]

Comment: can someone plz help me out... @Phill_P

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say that setting **one** ending node for your main activity can be enough. The ending node represent the termination of the whole activity you depict in your diagram. Thus the ending nodes as you put them are clearly invalid.

You can however describe ViewDetails and EditDetails with sub-activities. It that case, you can also terminate them with an ending point. In that case the ending is in the context of your activity. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409465.aspx#Details).

Personally I would create distinct diagrams for such a purpose but it seems that it is possible to represent this inside an action.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram You have drawn so far is wrong. Activity diagrams represent the flow of control from activity to activity in the system.In your diagram **"My profile"** should  not be an activity.And you need to represent activities in **rounded rectangles**.You can make **decision point** to separate the "**view details**" activity from the "**Edit details**" activity. Typically there is one starting point for the workflow and there may  be more than one ending point. (one for each alternate flow in the workflow)